# How to make a kivymd page navigation and insert some categories at the main menu?

Tags: python, mobile, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I am very new with kivymd and I got the layout to the main menu, but I could not get how to create a navigation menu to redirect the user to Login page.

The main idea is to let the user click at the menu button to consult the different categories, but I have not found how to include these categories at the menu icon, can anyone help me on it?

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp

KV = """
BoxLayout:

    # Will always be at the bottom of the screen.
    MDBottomAppBar:

        MDToolbar:
            title: "Title"
            icon: "cart-plus"
            type: "bottom"
            left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: x]]
            mode: "end"
"""


class Shop(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


Shop().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

from kivymd.app import MDApp

KV = '''
<ContentNavigationDrawer>:

    ScrollView:

        MDList:

            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Screen 1"
                on_press:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.screen_manager.current = "scr 1"

            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Screen 2"
                on_press:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.screen_manager.current = "scr 2"


Screen:

    MDToolbar:
        id: toolbar
        pos_hint: {"top": 1}
        elevation: 10
        title: "MDNavigationDrawer"
        left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]

    NavigationLayout:
        x: toolbar.height

        ScreenManager:
            id: screen_manager

            Screen:
                name: "scr 1"

                MDLabel:
                    text: "Screen 1"
                    halign: "center"

            Screen:
                name: "scr 2"

                MDLabel:
                    text: "Screen 2"
                    halign: "center"

        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer

            ContentNavigationDrawer:
                screen_manager: screen_manager
                nav_drawer: nav_drawer
'''


class ContentNavigationDrawer(BoxLayout):
    screen_manager = ObjectProperty()
    nav_drawer = ObjectProperty()


class TestNavigationDrawer(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


TestNavigationDrawer().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

from kivymd.app import MDApp

KV = '''
<ContentNavigationDrawer>:

    ScrollView:

        MDList:

            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Screen 1"
                on_press:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.screen_manager.current = "scr 1"

            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Screen 2"
                on_press:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.screen_manager.current = "scr 2"


Screen:

    MDToolbar:
        id: toolbar
        pos_hint: {"top": 1}
        elevation: 10
        title: "MDNavigationDrawer"
        left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]

    MDNavigationLayout:
        x: toolbar.height

        ScreenManager:
            id: screen_manager

            Screen:
                name: "scr 1"

                MDLabel:
                    text: "Screen 1"
                    halign: "center"

            Screen:
                name: "scr 2"

                MDLabel:
                    text: "Screen 2"
                    halign: "center"

        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer

            ContentNavigationDrawer:
                screen_manager: screen_manager
                nav_drawer: nav_drawer
'''


class ContentNavigationDrawer(BoxLayout):
    screen_manager = ObjectProperty()
    nav_drawer = ObjectProperty()


class TestNavigationDrawer(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


TestNavigationDrawer().run()
```

[for more information see the official documentation ok KivyMD](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/)

Hope this Helped you!